# Primefaces RadioButton, JS functions is not working

Tags: javascript, primefaces, xhtml

I have a problem with 3 radio button in a xhtml file, when I click on a radio button to call onclick JS function it enter in the function the first time, but next time I will click the same button or another one the function will be not executed.
The radio button selected at the page reload will execute the function properly, but when I select another one and then come back to the first one or the third the JS function will be not executed.

Here a short part of the xhtml code:

```
<ui:component xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:s="http://jboss.org/seam/faces"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<p:outputPanel id="identificationMethod">

    <p:selectOneRadio id="identificationMethodRadio"
                    validator="required"
                    requiredMessage="SELECT CONFIRMATION METHOD"
                    layout="custom"
                    value="#{identificationMethodSelector.identificationMethod}">
        <p:ajax update="identificationMethod" global="false"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{identificationMethodSelector.identificationMethodList}" />
    </p:selectOneRadio>

    <ui:fragment rendered="#{!hideIdentificationMethodNone and user.enableIdentificationMethodNone}">
        <div>
            <p:radioButton id="identificationMethodNone" for="identificationMethodRadio" itemIndex="5" />
            <h:outputLabel for="identificationMethodNone"
                        value="NOT NOW" />

            <ui:fragment rendered="true">
                <div class="identificationMessage">
                    <div class="spacer" />
                    <span>xxxxxxxxx</span><br />
                    <div class="spacer" />
                </div>
            </ui:fragment>
        </div>
    </ui:fragment>
```

Here the JS:

```
    var none = document.getElementById('identificationMethodNone');
    var radioImg = document.getElementById('identificationMethodImage');
    var tel = document.getElementById('identificationMethodTel');

    radioImg.onclick = function (event){
        console.log("CLICK ON IMG");
    };

    none.onclick = function (event){
        console.log("CLICK ON NONE");
    };

   tel.onclick = function (event){
        console.log("CLICK ON TEL");
    };
```

As you can see the JS have no problem I think, really simple JS, tried on another simbple html file and it works properly.

While trying a lot of thinks I discovered that deleting this line of code the JS function will work properly:

```
<p:ajax update="identificationMethod" global="false"/>
```

But deleting this line other things breaks.
How can I fix this without editing too much the XHTML code?
Thanks

Comment: After your click, the whole panel identificationMethod gets updated because of `<p:ajax update="identificationMethod" global="false"/>`. You have to reinstall your onclick handlers or update a smaller part. Try to place your javascript code inside the updated panel.

Comment: Or register your eventhandlers more dynamically